# Use of return in catch block?

Tags: java, swing

I am building a GPA calculator java application using swing API first time. This is my first GUI application.

I have handled 3 exceptions in the following cases

- if the user enters a decimal value
- if the user enters a negative value
- if the user leaves the text field blank.

I have used return keyword in the catch block (especially in `ArithmeticException` case) because the program was still calculating the GPA even after the error message was shown (I didn't want that).

Although the code is working fine like I want it to, is using a `return` as shown in my code a correct/good approach to my problem?

Code:

```
try{
    int temp;
    temp = Integer.parseInt(c1.getText());
    if(temp < 0){
        throw(new ArithmeticException());
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please fill the fields with proper values.");
     return;
}
catch(ArithmeticException e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"negative values not allowed");
     return;
}
```

Comment: The bad practice here is to throw an exception, and catch it immediately. You don't need to throw `ArithmeticException` (and won't be thrown otherwise), just show the message and return if it is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that return statements are completely down to the invidivual. Some people don't like them, some people do.

Personally, I like them, and I find it can make code easier to read. However some people feel the other way. Your alternative is too check a condition, output the result to a boolean, and only run your code if the boolean matches what you expect.

Also, throwing an Exception causes java to do a lot more work than if you were to just do the check directly.

This would be cleaner:

```
try{
    int temp;
    temp = Integer.parseInt(c1.getText());
    if(temp < 0){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"negative values not allowed");
     return;
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please fill the fields with proper values.");
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no other code after this:

```
try{
    int temp;
    temp = Integer.parseInt(c1.getText());
    if(temp < 0){
        throw(new ArithmeticException());
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please fill the fields with proper values.");
     return;
}
catch(ArithmeticException e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"negative values not allowed");
     return;
}
```

then you can remove the `return` clause to make it cleaner, it is totally unecessary.

Comment: Whilst you are correct in the case you give, we don't know if OP does have code after this try statement. I suggest you ask for clarification on the question, as this answer might simply not be relevant.